# ld: error in (.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be create

Tags: linux, linker, debian

I make a very simple program hello in C. When use ld in the exe file returns this

```
ld: error in hello(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
```

I don't define any `LD_LIBRAY_PATH` or paths in `/etc/ld.so.conf` I've tried the same with the ls and returns:

```
ld: error in /bin/ls(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000402920
```

What's happening? I'm using a Debian and my GCC version is (Debian **4.7.2-5**).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and use code (**{}**) button to format code properly.

Comment: Did you spell library wrong?

Comment: No I only make `ld hello` and `ld /bin/ls`

Comment: Any particular reason you're using ld directly?  The normal way to compile and link a C program would be directly from the C compiler, for instance "gcc hello.c -o hello"

Answer (score 8):

I believe the utility you meant to use was ldd (LDD), not ld.

ldd will show all the shared linked libraries your exe uses.. or, at least, were linked it at compile time.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you understand what ld does.  ld takes "object files" (code that has been compiled but not linked, usually stored in .o files) and libraries (sets of object files collected into a single .a or .so file), and joins them to produce an executable that the operating system can run.

When you invoke ld with a single argument, it expects that argument to be an object file.  In your case, you're using it on "hello" and "/bin/ls", which are executables that have already been linked, thereby producing the (admittedly confusing) error message.

I suspect that your confusion stems from the fact that when you compile your source with gcc, it will also link it with the standard library and produce an executable file (like "hello") unless you specifically tell it not to.  No separate linking step is necessary.

For reference, here are the [gcc manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) and the [ld manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld).